# Notation for factorial-type pattern with a skip/step of two instead of one?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, factorial, pattern-recognition

I came across a peculiar pattern when solving a recurrence relation today:

Some sequence $a_n$ looks as such:

$a_0 = 1$

$a_2 = \frac{1}{2 \cdot 1}$

$a_4 = \frac{1}{4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$

$a_6 = \frac{1}{6 \cdot 4 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}$

...

The pattern is quite simple, but I can't think of a way to express the general equation for $a_n$

EDIT:

The recurrence relation is

$a_{n+2} = \frac{1}{n+2} \cdot a_n$

so the odd indices' denominators would be 1, 3, 5*3, 7*5*3, etc.

Any pointers?

Comment: What are the odd-indexed terms supposed to be?

Comment: [Double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Well... that is indeed what I was looking for. Didn't know that notation existed!

Comment: The next time you encounter a sequence of integers, it would benefit you greatly to look them up first in the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/); in particular, searching for the sequence $1, 2, 3, 8, 15, 48, 105, 384, 945, 3840,\dots$ gives [this](https://oeis.org/A006882).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for probably this piece of notation, called **double factorial**:

$$n!!= \begin{cases}n \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-4) \cdots 3 \cdot 1, &\text{$n \gt 0$, n odd}\\ n \cdot (n-2) \cdot (n-4) \cdots 4 \cdot 2, &\text{$n \gt 0$, n even} \\ 1,  &\text{$n=-1,0$}\end{cases}$$

Most conveniently, we would write it as $$\begin{align}(2n)!!&=2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6 \cdots 2n~~ \mbox{for}~~ n \in \Bbb N \\(2n+1)!!&=1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdots (2n+1)~~ \mbox{for}~~ n \in \Bbb N\end{align}$$

**Some relations connecting these quantities:**

- $(2n)!!=\prod_{i=1}^n(2i)=2^n\prod_{i=1}^n i=2^nn!$
- $(2n+1)!!(2n)!!=(2n+1)!$ obviously.

---

For the problem at hand, your terms are $$a_n=\dfrac 1 {n!!}$$

---

Analogously, one could define functions like primorial, triple factorial, quadruple factorials and so on. For a more extended note on this kind of definitions, please follow [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Factorial-like_products_and_functions) link.

Comment: ...and analogously there are "triple factorials", "quadruple factorials", and so on. On that note: there are the convenient relations $(2n)!!=2^n n!$ and $(2n)!!(2n+1)!!=(2n+1)!$.

Comment: @J.M. I was about to add all of that. But, my bad, the cases environment looks horrible. I'll edit to add all of that. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, a slightly non-standard use of double-factorial gives
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{n!!}
$$
for even $n$. However, I usually see double factorial used with odd $n$. For even $n$,
$$
a_n=\frac{1}{2^{n/2}(n/2)!}
$$
works as well.

For odd $n$, without double factorial,
$$
a_n=\frac{2^{(n-1)/2}(\frac{n-1}{2})!}{n!}
$$
so it is easy to see why $1/n!!$ is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

It is written $n!!$ and denoted the [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Double_factorial).